# SelectionChanged Event for ListBox. Pass parameters between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building a WP7 app that consist on one listbox in the first page to show the id of several task and a detail page to show the details for each task (selected).

I need to pass the task id from the first page to the second one. I know that it is carried out by SelectionChanged event of the listbox.

This is my XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="TaskListAlpha03.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="696"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"    
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TaskListListBoxTemplate">            
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,20">                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Crm_object_id}" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold" Foreground="Gray"/>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>              -->
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,40">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="TASK LIST ALPHA" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="tasks" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox 
                        x:Name="allTaskListTasksListBox" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AllTaskListTasks}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskListListBoxTemplate}"
                        SelectionChanged="allTaskListTasksListBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And this is the cs code:

```
    private void allTaskListTasksListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Details.xaml?msg=" + lbi.Content.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

In the second page I have this sample code to check if it works:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo
        (System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string msg = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
                PageTitle.Text = msg;
        }
```

When I execute the application I have a "NullReferenceException".

Sorry for my english :S and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points here...
1) I would use a Tap event on the item rather than a selection changed event.  It helps prevent accidental navigation.
2) If you *do* use the selectionchanged event, try the following code to get your item.  Your current code will attempt to fire if an items is de-selected in the list.

```
private void allTaskListTasksListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0) // the items that were added to the "selected" collection
    {
        var mySelectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as myItemType;
        if(null != mySelectedItem) // prevents errors if casting fails
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(
               new Uri("/View/Details.xaml?msg=" + mySelectedItem.Crm_object_id, 
                       UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);`. You are casting it to ListBoxItem which in fact it is your custom item you bind it to the ListBox. Do something like:

`var item = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as YourItem);`